# What type of Font can this be

Tags: fonts

[image]

What type of Font is on this Picture??

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE community. The same font in free distribuition not exist...but you can choose calligra font. See this link https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/calligra/

Comment: A badly kerned font — the space between the N and the a…

Comment: @Thérèse I have suggest to the user a nice compromise. That font it is not included in TeXLive or MikTeK but it can be a .ttf or .otf. external to LaTeX.

Comment: It **is not** Helinda Rook Regular (https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/athelinda-rook/athelinda-rook/), but that's the closest myfonts suggested!